# Pick random numbers from different ranges, what is the probability each is greatest?

Tags: probability

Suppose the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent distributed uniformly with different bounds: $X_i \sim U(0, x_i)$. What is the probability of "$X_i$ is the greatest number" for each $i$?

We can assume $x_1=1$ and $x_1 \ge x_2 \ge \cdots \ge x_n$. I'm more interested in the inverse problem of how to pick the parameters $x_i$ given the probabilities for "$X_i$ is the greatest number" but working out the relationship between the bounds and the probabilities seems like a necessary intermediate step.

I have solved this for $n=2$ and $n=3$ with geometric methods but I don't see any way to generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try conditioning:
\begin{align}
\Pr( X_k \geq X_j \forall j \neq k) &= \frac{1}{x_k} \int_0^{x_k} \Pr( X_k \geq X_j \forall j \neq k | X_k = x)x \mathrm{d} x 
\end{align}

I think you will have to split the integral into different parts 0 to $x_1$, $x_1$ to $x_2$, etc.

Comment: The important part now is that the probability under the integral is about lots of *independent* events, so it can be easily numerically calculated as a product. If you need a closed formula, then, as stated, you will have to do it in intervals between the $x_i$

Comment: Thank you! By breaking the integral into intervals I was able to find a simple recurrence relation that makes computations very easy.